# Saving Files to SQL server using knockout js

Tags: file-upload, knockout.js

I have a requirement on my web app to save multiple attachments to my SQL server. The attachments can be in any format. Is it possible to create a knockout viewmodel to encode the file type on client side to binary and transferring that binary info to my SQL server?

I currently have this method in my REST service:

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string PostAttachments (string  FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var MyAttachment = new Binary(File.ReadAllBytes(FileName));
            return "Attachments Created";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return DefaultError + ex;
        }

    }
```

I know this is incorrect but I am really not sure how to do this file upload. I believe I am over complicating it. Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to transfer the buffer to the server not just the filename, since the file exists on the client.

I used the HTML5 FileReader in my last KO project

First a custom binding to read the file from the DOM element

```
(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.file = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                writeValueToProperty(valueAccessor(), allBindingsAccessor, "file", element.files[0]);
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) == null) {
                element.value = "";
            }
        }
    };

    var writeValueToProperty = function (property, allBindingsAccessor, key, value, checkIfDifferent) {
        if (!property || !ko.isObservable(property)) {
            var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()['_ko_property_writers'];
            if (propWriters && propWriters[key])
                propWriters[key](value);
        } else if (ko.isWriteableObservable(property) && (!checkIfDifferent || property.peek() !== value)) {
            property(value);
        }
    };
} ());
```

FileReader usage (code specific for how I used it in my app). Check the FileReader part only.
Note if you have large files you need to stream instead

```
processFiles: function (viewModel, callback) {
        var files = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.files, function (file) {
            if (file.fileUpload() == null) return;
            var count = Enumerable.From(viewModel.files)
                .Where(function(f) { return f.fileUpload() != null; })
                .Count();

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var base64 = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",") + 1);
                files.push({ Type: file.type, Data: base64, Filename: file.fileUpload().name });

                if (files.length == count) {
                    callback(files);
                }
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file.fileUpload());
        });
    }
```

**Update**
Like said this is code for my use case, you will need to change it to fit your purpose

```
<div data-bind="foreach: files">
    <p><label data-bind="text: typeName"></label><input data-bind="file: fileUpload" type="file" /></p>            
</div>
```

Controller (I would use WebApi if I did this today)

```
public JsonResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<FileUploadViewModel> uploads)
{        
    fileRepository.SaveUploadedFiles(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FileUploadViewModel>, IEnumerable <FileUpload>> (uploads));
    return string.Empty.AsJson();
}
```

FileUploadViewModel

```
public class FileUploadViewModel
{
    public FileType Type { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper config

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FileUploadViewModel, FileUpload>()
      .ForMember(to => to.Buffer, opt => opt.MapFrom(from => Convert.FromBase64String(from.Data)));
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML and the LINQ to SQL Code of how it more or less will look?

Comment: I updated with more code. btw, FileType is domain specific its not the mimetype in this case

Comment: Updated with Automapper config